# Extbase disjunction validation syntax

Tags: validation, typo3, extbase, logical-or

I have a User model with a email property:

```
/**
 * email
 *
 * @var string
 */
protected $email = '';
```

I could not find any docs related to the disjunction validator annotation syntax, other than this cheat sheet: http://www.lobacher.de/files/cs/ExtbaseFluidCheatSheet_3.02_pluswerk.pdf, 
which does not seem to work.
This is that I've tried:

```
@validate Disjunction(EmailAddress,NotEmpty)
@validate OR:Disjunction(0:EmailAddress,1:NotEmpty)
@validate Disjunction(0:EmailAddress,1:NotEmpty)
@validate Disjunction(0=EmailAddress,1=NotEmpty)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`EmailAddress` only throws an error if the value is set. 
So you do not have to specify `NotEmpty` at all to achieve your desired behavior.